# Escape variable in sqlcmd / Invoke-SqlCmd

Tags: sql-server, windows, powershell, sqlcmd, invoke-sqlcmd

I am using powershell and using [`Invoke-SqlCmd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/cc281720.aspx).  I am able to pass variables to SQL:

```
$variables = @( "MyVariable='hello'" )

Invoke-SqlCmd `
    -ServerInstance 'localhost' `
    -Database 'master' `
    -Username 'matthew' `
    -Password 'qwerty' `
    -Query 'SELECT $(MyVariable) AS foo' `
    -Variable $variables
```

This gives me back `hello` as expected.  However, if I have a variable with a value containing an equals (`=`):

```
$variables = @("MyVariable='aGVsbG8NCg=='") # base64 encoded 'hello'
```

It gives me the following error:

> The format used to define the new variable for `Invoke-Sqlcmd` cmdlet is invalid. Please use the 'var=value' format for defining a new variable.

I could not find any documentation on either `sqlcmd` or `Invoke-SqlCmd` on how I should escape values properly.

How do I escape variables sent to `sqlcmd` / `Invoke-SqlCmd`?

Comment: Not only `-Variable` has problems with embedded `=`, it also does not parametrize the SQL command. It substitutes whatever goes after the `=` in the `name=value` clause into the SQL text, which is the reason why you need to put the `value` in single quotes - they are not treated specially, they are just dumped in the SQL. If the parameter value comes from outside, you have to escape it yourself to make it a valid and safe SQL string literal, complete with single quotes, before you pass it to `Invoke-SqlCmd`.

Comment: @GSerg this is true unless your script already has the single quotes in it. i.e. '$(myVar)', then just the value is needed, otherwise you create a TSQL syntax error.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After investigating using some reflection on

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\SQLPS\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PSSnapins.dll

Looking at `ExecutionProcessor`'s constructor, the following lines reveal the problem that it will fail if there are more than one equals sign in the variable definition.

My recommendation for anyone else trying to use `Invoke-SqlCmd` is to save your time and sanity and just use the open source alternative [Invoke-SqlCmd2](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PowerShell/blob/master/Invoke-Sqlcmd2.ps1) instead.

Microsoft, please fix.

Comment: Thanks for doing the digging and finding the root cause Matthew. That saved me time trying to finangle my code to get it to work with Invoke-Sqlcmd knowing that there was not going to be a clean solution.

Answer (score 12):

Use `CHAR(61)` to replace the equal sign.

```
$variable = "'Hello=World'"
$variables = @( "MyVariable=$($variable.replace("=","'+CHAR(61)+'"))" )

Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance 'localhost' -Database 'master' -Query 'SELECT $(MyVariable) AS foo' -Variable $variables
```

Comment: This helped me get around an issue with Powershell and $( in my SQL script. I used CHAR(36) instead of the $ symbol, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I also found myself needing to pass a base64 encoded piece of information which had those pesky '='s in them. What worked for me was adding a replacement token into the variable array that I pass to the query and then using SQL's REPLACE function in my query to replace my token with an '=' sign.

So you can update your code to look like this:

```
$equalsSignReplacement = '[EQUALSIGN]'
$myVariable = 'aGVsbG8NCg=='
$variables = 
    "EqualsSignReplacement=$($equalsSignReplacement)",
    "MyVariable=$($myVariable.Replace('=',$equalsSignReplacement))"

Invoke-SqlCmd `
    -ServerInstance 'localhost' `
    -Database 'master' `
    -Username 'matthew' `
    -Password 'qwerty' `
    -Query 'SELECT REPLACE('$(MyVariable)','$(EqualsSignReplacement)','=') AS foo' `
    -Variable $variables
```

The downside to this solution is that you need to be proactive with it's application. You need to know ahead of time which variables might have an 'equals sign' in them and then update not only your powershell code, but also your SQL scripts to make sure that the replacement happens correctly.

Just be sure to use a replacement token that is unique to your variables so you don't accidentally replace valid text with '=' in your queries.

Comment: Is it possible to pass variable to -InputFile ?

Answer (score 0):

I encounted this issue recently and had success using the answer from TheMadTechnician at:

[Replace Single Quotes in PowerShell Or Excel CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24292950/replace-single-quotes-in-powershell-or-excel-csv)

> The answer is to create sub expressions in your string to replace '
>   with ''.
>
> `Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "$SQLServer" -Database "$SqlDB" -query "INSERT INTO dbo.ecca_sw_standard_2 (name, version, product_id) VALUES (N'$($CSVAppName -replace "'", "''")', N'$($CSVVersion -replace "'", "''")' , N'$($CSVAppID -replace "'", "''")')"`
>
> This way when the
>   string is expanded it will be appropriately escaped for SQL insertion.

Comment: Even though this might address OP's question, for future reference of link only answers, please write down the components which address the problem. In the event that the link breaks down, the answer still lives on.