# invoke-sqlcmd empty variable

Tags: powershell, invoke-sqlcmd

I am trying to perform an SQL query using `Invoke-SqlCmd` launching script as inputfile which contains SQLCMD variables, as $(varPROJECTNAME).

For example:
`CREATE DATABASE [$(varPROJECTNAME)$(varDBNAME)]`
In such a case, i want to be able to set an empty string as `varPROJECTNAME` value.

This request will run successfully with classical SQLCMD tool, but with Invoke-SqlCmd, i get error, script variable varPROJECTNAME is undefined.

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd  -Username $LoginSQL -Password $PasswordSQL -ServerInstance $InstanceSQL -Verbose  -InputFile "$rootPackage\DB\UpdateDB\00-initSql\00-SubsTechCreateDatabase.sql"  -Variable "varPROJECTNAME=$projectName","varDBNAME=$DatabaseName"
```

In case above, if   `$projectName=""`, There will be an error

Is it possible to set a default value calling Invoke-SqlCmd, or from sql script point of view, assign a default value to the variable when it's undefined?

Many thanks in advance for your help

Comment: We might wanna need more description and code as well,the question is very unclear

Comment: `sqlcmd.exe` doesn't like it if you do that either: `sqlcmd -Q "SELECT '$(var)'"` -> `"'var' scripting variable not defined."` It will then proceed anyway, leaving the variable without any substitution, literally as `$(var)` (unless you pass `-b`, then the batch is aborted and nothing happens, in the same manner as `Invoke-SqlCmd`). Relying on this is ill-advised. If you must do this, I recommend identifying the variables and explicitly passing empty values anyway.

Comment: That is the problem in fact, passing empty variables with SQLCMD will work; in your case, if var=='' it is an empty string that will be used in executed query. With Invoke-SqlCmd, the query will not run at all, despite i explicitly set variable to ''

Comment: `invoke-sqlcmd 'SELECT $(var)' -Variable "var=''"` -> no error. You'll have to supply code that fails.

Comment: invoke-sqlcmd 'SELECT $(var)' -Variable "var=" in my case will fail; sorry for beeing unclar

Comment: Hey man, your question is getting downvoted because you haven't provided a good example of your current code, and your description of what you want to accomplish is kind of confusing.  Can you edit your question to include a code sample that you're working on, and we'll try to help you out?

Comment: OK, I see the problem. `sqlcmd -Q "SELECT '$(var)'" -v var=""` works and selects the empty string, `invoke-sqlcmd 'SELECT ''$(var)''' -Variable "var="` will not work because you can't pass the empty string (at least not that way). (Yes, having this in the question helps, comments are fleeting.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert exactly!

Comment: @FoxDeploy il will edit my post, but you can look at JereoMostert comment

Comment: Can you write temporary files? If so, abandoning the primitive variable substitution of SQLCMD and doing it in PowerShell is an option. It's clumsy, but a `(Get-Content $inputfile).Replace('$(varPROJECTNAME)', "$projectname") | Out-File -Enc Utf8 tempscript.sql` would make a new script with the variable pre-substituted. Doing this dynamically for all variables is a bit more code.

Comment: Silly me, there's a `-Query` parameter you could pass the contents of the script to directly, of course, so you'd have no need of temporary files (they could still be good to see substitutions and/or speed things up).

Comment: hmm, yous suggestion sounds good @JeroenMostert ! :-)
I'll try it right now

Comment: Great! @JeroenMostert, your comment is ok for me; i can accept it as an Answer if you post it as it. 
However, from a Invoke_SqlCmd point of view, and if there is no other sollution, I consider that this is a limitation

Comment: It is a limitation, but not the only one; if you look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35157090/), someone else wrestled with the fact that `=` couldn't be used in a variable at all. (The alternative script mentioned there might be something for you as well, but I haven't checked.) `Invoke-SqlCmd` is a bit dodgy, considering doozies like [executing failed scripts twice](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/811560) (that has since been fixed, fortunately). At present I lack the time to write up a decent answer, feel free to post one yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the `Invoke-SQLCommand` tool is very helpfully running some error checking, ensuring that all of the variables which you've defined here are passed along to SQL to setup your database just so.

I would propose a change, let's add some logic to your script to see if you've specified a `$ProjectName` value, and if so, pass that value along.  If not, run a slightly different command instead.

```
If($projectName -ne $null){
 $variables = "varPROJECTNAME=$projectName","varDBNAME=$DatabaseName"
   }
 else{
 $variables = "varDBNAME=$DatabaseName"
  }

Invoke-Sqlcmd  -Username $LoginSQL -Password $PasswordSQL -ServerInstance $InstanceSQL `
  -Verbose  -InputFile "$rootPackage\DB\UpdateDB\00-initSql\00-SubsTechCreateDatabase.sql" `
  -Variable $variables
```

## Edit

Could you try this example instead?

In your current code, replace this

```
-Variable "varPROJECTNAME=$projectName"
```

with

```
-Variable "varPROJECTNAME=`"$($projectName)`""
```

Comment: That's not going to work, because the whole command fails if you leave a variable unspecified. As long as the `.sql` contains `$(varPROJECTNAME)`, it must be passed explicitly.

Comment: In this example, we only pass variables with values.  Notice that line 2 passes both varProjectName and varDBName, while line 5 only provides a value for varDBName.  This should solve your issue.

Comment: well no, Jeroen is right, your proposal  will solve only your powershell issue, but the script will not run as varPROJECTNAME is not set on SQL side

Comment: Oh, so you're saying that your SQL Script .`SQL` File might have a blank value for `varPROJECTNAME`? Can you try the second example?

Comment: @FoxDeploy, thanks for your suggestion, i tried it but unsuccessfully

Answer (score 0):

Coalescing to '""' in PowerShell and then checking for that in SQL worked for me.

PowerShell:

```
# coalesce command if undefined, whitespace or empty
if ("$($step.command)".Trim().Length -eq 0) {
    $command = '""'
} else {
    $command = $($step.command)
}

$variables = @(
    "job_name=$($job.name)",
    "step_name=$($step.name)",
    "step_id=$($step.id)",
    "package_path=$($step.package)",
    "command=$command",
    ...
)

Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile "$PSScriptRoot\upsert_job_step.sql" -Variable $variables -ConnectionString $connString -Verbose -OutputSqlErrors $true
```

SQL:

```
DECLARE @command varchar(2047) = CASE
  WHEN NULLIF(TRIM('$(command)'), '""') IS NOT NULL
  THEN '$(command)'
  ELSE  FORMATMESSAGE('/ISSERVER "\"\SSISDB\$(package_path)\"" /ENVREFERENCE %i ..., @referenceId)
END;
```

The value can be anything (say `undefined` or `null`) it just needs to be the same in both scripts.