# Executing an OPENROWSET on azure synapse result in a 'Resolving CosmosDB path has failed with error 'Secret is not base64 encoded.''

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, credentials, azure-synapse, openrowset

I am deploying to an azure synapse environment queries using sqlcmd to serverless pool.
The environment contains an SQL database that my deploying account has access to.

I am creating first the credentials to access a cosmosDB with :

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL [mycosmos] WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE', SECRET = '<accessKeyToCosmosAccount>'
```

Then using the openrowset with the created credentials to retrieve records from the aforementioned COSMOSDB

```
SELECT TOP (100) *
from OPENROWSET (
    PROVIDER = 'CosmosDB',
    CONNECTION = 'Account=mycosmos;Database=reporting;',
    OBJECT = 'data',
    CREDENTIAL = 'mycosmos'
) as o;
```

however executing the latter gives the following error:
`Resolving CosmosDB path has failed with error 'Secret is not base64 encoded.'.`

Does anyone has tips or ideas on how to get more information or to understand the issue at hand?

the credentials are indeed created and I checked that by using:

```
SELECT * FROM SYS.database_scoped_credentials
```

I also tried to base64 the secret `accessKeyToCosmosAccount` using

```
echo $mysecret | tr -d '\n\r' | base64 -w 0
```

to no avail (I still keep getting the same error)

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce similar scenario in my environment and faced similar error.

[image]

After researching **I found that cause of error is the incorrect secret.**
To resolve this, check your secret/primary key is correct.

To get connection string you can **go to your cosmos db account >> Settings >> Keys >> Primary Key.**

[image]

**My code:**

```sql
CREATE  CREDENTIAL MyCosmosDbAccountCredential
WITH  IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE', SECRET = 'primary key from cosmos db';

SELECT  TOP  10 *
FROM  OPENROWSET(
PROVIDER = 'CosmosDB',
CONNECTION = 'Account=cosmosdb_name;Database=databassename',
OBJECT = 'container2',
SERVER_CREDENTIAL = 'MyCosmosDbAccountCredential1'
) with ( id varchar(10), name  varchar(10) ) as  rows
```

**Execution and Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks for your quick answer. turns out it was indeed the secret which we retrieve with an `az cosmosdb keys list --name <name> -g <resource-group> --query 'primaryReadonlyMasterKey' -o tsv`

Something wrong happens when we use the sqlcmd and pass the secret with -v.
turns out passing variables with `=` sign results in sqlcmd trimming the rest (see [Escape variable in sqlcmd / Invoke-SqlCmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35157090/escape-variable-in-sqlcmd-invoke-sqlcmd#answer-35158611))

I think this issue is not much relevant to Synapse than it is to sqlcmd. I will continue the conversation there.