# Invoke-Sqlcmd variable format is invalid with Powershell, variable value contains equals sign

Tags: sql, powershell, invoke-sqlcmd

I took an example from the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd) to add the variable of Invoke-Sqlcmd

```
$StringArray = "MYVAR1='String1'", "MYVAR2='String2'"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT `$(MYVAR1) AS Var1, `$(MYVAR2) AS Var2" -Variable $StringArray

Var1     Var2
----     ----
String1  String2
```

But the value of the variable cannot have an equal sign, here is an example

```
$StringArray = "MYVAR1='String1'", "MYVAR2='String2=String3'"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT `$(MYVAR1) AS Var1, `$(MYVAR2) AS Var2" -Variable $StringArray
```

I got error:
`Invoke-Sqlcmd : The format used to define the new variable for Invoke-Sqlcmd cmdlet is invalid. Please use the 'var=value' format for defining a new variable.`

Is there any way to bypass that.

Comment: Use semicolon to separate SQL commands.  You either need a return between commands or a semicolon (not comma).

Comment: If your Sql module is V22+ you can try and use a Hashtable instead of an array: 
`$var = @{MYVAR1='String1'; MYVAR2='String2=String3'}`

Comment: There’s a similar / duplicate question here that has some kludgy workarounds like using “replace” in the sql query to substitute a known placeholder in the variable value for an equals sign… https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35157090/escape-variable-in-sqlcmd-invoke-sqlcmd. It’s hacky, but looks like a limitation of ```Invoke-SqlCmd```

Comment: Another option I found could be to replace the `=` in the variable value by `CHAR(61)` like this: `$StringArray = "MYVAR1='String1'", "MYVAR2='$('String2=String3'.Replace('=', "'+CHAR(61)+'"))'"`

Comment: @jdweng, there's only _one_ query in the question, so your comment doesn't apply and is an unnecessary distraction. Please consider deleting it.